# JSTL foreach on result set

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, resultset

Hey friends, i want to know that, Is there any way to apply `<c:foreach>` on a resultset object. If yes ,than please give me an idea , how can we do this ?

Answer (score 3):

It accepts only any type of `Collection` , [`ResultSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) isn't.

Comment: So what is the solution to iterate?

Comment: @Baad convert result set to Collection of object and then pass it to view

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways that you could make a `ResultSet` available to `<c:forEach>`. One of those is to enlist the help of the JSTL API, specifically [`ResultSupport.toResult(ResultSet)`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/sql/ResultSupport.html#toResult%28java.sql.ResultSet%29). This will create a `Result` instance that you can then use to provide input to `<c:forEach>` through such methods as [`getRows`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/sql/Result.html#getRows%28%29) or [`getRowsByIndex`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/sql/Result.html#getRowsByIndex%28%29).